# easy hex/float conversion

Tags: c++, python, formatting, floating-point, hex

I am doing some input/output between a c++ and a python program (only floating point values) python has a nice feature of converting floating point values to hex-numbers and back as you can see in this link:

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-float

Is there an easy way in C++ to to something similar? and convert the python output back to C++ double/float? This way I would not have the problem of rounding errors when exchanging data between the two processes...

thx for the answers!

Comment: The "rounding errors" are low-order bits without meaningful values.  They're (a) decimal to binary issues; they could also be (b) junk bits left over from doing division and multiplication unwisely.  Simply passing "raw" float values around may not help you very much if your numeric methods are unsound to begin with.

Comment: you are right... . But I can't get rid of the error (b) in my simulation (my simulations just for themselfs work and proved to be accurate). I now need to exchange some information between different simulations and why introduce an error, when it can be done otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the link you provided in your question ([Additional Methods on Float](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-float)):

> This syntax is similar to the syntax
>   specified in section 6.4.4.2 of the
>   C99 standard, and also to the syntax
>   used in Java 1.5 onwards. In
>   particular, the output of float.hex() 
>   is usable as a hexadecimal
>   floating-point literal in C or Java
>   code, and hexadecimal strings produced
>   by C’s %a format character or Java’s
>   Double.toHexString  are accepted by
>   float.fromhex().

Example:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  float f = 42.79;
  printf("%.2f == %a\n", f, f);  
  fscanf(stdin, "%a", &f);
  printf("%.2f == %a\n", f, f);  
}
```

Run it:

```
$ g++ *.cpp && (python -c'print 12.34.hex()' | ./a.out )
```

Output:

```
42.79 == 0x1.5651ecp+5
12.34 == 0x1.8ae148p+3
```

Comment: hi, I tried to run the same program, but I got 42.79 == 0x1.5651ecp+5
0.00 == 0x0p+0. My python outputs 0x1.8ae147ae147aep+3, somehow c++ did not read in this correctly. Do you happend to know why? Thanks a lot.

Comment: even if I just ran ./a.out and type in 0x1.5651ecp+5, it still produced 0.00 == 0x0p+0

Comment: @Qiang Li: What are your compiler, OS, *exact* commands you use?

Comment: @Qiang Li: are you sure you use `%a` (and not e.g, `%d`). Run `g++ --version; cat *.cpp` and paste the results.

Comment: Yes, I am using %a. Weird enough, I did not find %a format specifier though. Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
I also tried g++ (GCC) 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1
Copyright (c) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: @Qiang Li: It works on gcc 4.1, 4.5; clang 2.8. Copy the text of the program from the question as-is and run: `xclip -o | gcc -x c++ - -o f && (python -c'print 12.34.hex()' | ./f )`

Answer (score 2):

Can you send raw binary data between the two instead of strings?  The [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) package of Python's standard library can unpack the raw data into a Python float object.

Comment: hey cool... I did not know about that python feature. I will definitly look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The docs there say that `%a` does this in C.

Answer (score 1):

You're sorely mistaken if you believe that this will solve all your problems. The hex notation is exactly equivalent to the original float. It just uses a different representation.

Comment: He's exchanging strings.  The hex notation is exactly equivalent to the original float, which is why he wants it.  A regular decimal string may include rounding errors.

Comment: @Daniel: In that case he might be better off using something like `gmp` if the string representation is that important.

Comment: Thx for the hint to gmp I did not know that library either. Its an interesting alternativ. But for my simple problem its a probably a little overkill.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not have any library routines for converting hex to floating point.  One reason is that the internal representation of floating point is not standardized (although many compilers do use an IEEE standard).

I recommend storing in ASCII format, which is portable across platforms.  You could write your own library (or find another) which will convert between an IEEE format (in hex) to the internal representation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a platform whose system C library supports C99, you can just use `printf( )` and `scanf( )` with the `%a` format specifier.  For reading in such values, you can also use the C99 `strtod( )`, `strtof( )`, and `strtold( )` functions:

```
float value = strtof(string, NULL, 0);
```

You can optionally replace `NULL` with a `char **` to get back a pointer to the end of the sequence of converted characters, and `0` with a known base for the string representation (if you set the base to be zero, it will infer the base from the format; it will parse the python hex floats just fine, and also handle normal decimal-formatted floating point)

If your compiler/library vendor has chosen not to care about C99 (MSVC, basically), you're probably out of luck until these function are incorporated into the C++ standard (I believe that they're in the draft C++0x, but I'm not completely sure).

Answer (score 0):

C++11 offers std::hexfloat: [IO manipulators including hexfloat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)

If you can use C++11 then hexfloat is pretty easy to use.